# State machine in rust?

Tags: rust, syntax, state-machine

In the C family of languages I usually implement a state machine as a series of if else statements and enums, where if statements check in which state the machine is and the bodies execute state transitions, for example this:

```cpp
if(current_left_state == GLFW_PRESS && !left_pressed)
{
    left_pressed = true;
    return MouseInputState::LEFT_DOWN;
}
if(current_left_state == GLFW_PRESS && left_pressed)
{
    left_pressed = true;
    return MouseInputState::LEFT_DRAG;
}
if(current_left_state == GLFW_RELEASE && left_pressed)
{
    left_pressed = false;
    return MouseInputState::LEFT_UP;
}
if(current_right_state == GLFW_PRESS && !right_pressed)
{
    right_pressed = true;
    return MouseInputState::RIGHT_DOWN;
}
```

Rust has a lot of idiomatic sugar which is nice, I was wondering if there is a way to use rust's syntactic sugar to make cleaner state machines.

Like, there has got to be a better way than this:

```rust
MouseState::NoAction =>
{
    if *button == glfw::MouseButtonLeft && *action == glfw::Action::Press
    {
        return MouseState::LeftDown;
    }
    if *button == glfw::MouseButtonRight && *action == glfw::Action::Press
    {
        return MouseState::RightDown;
    }
    return MouseState::NoAction;
}
MouseState::LeftDown =>
{
    if *button == glfw::MouseButtonLeft && *action == glfw::Action::Release
    {
        return MouseState::LeftUp;
    }
    return MouseState::LeftDrag;
}
MouseState::LeftDrag =>
{
    if *button == glfw::MouseButtonLeft && *action == glfw::Action::Release
    {
        return MouseState::LeftUp;
    }
    return MouseState::LeftDrag;
}
MouseState::LeftUp =>
{
    if *button == glfw::MouseButtonLeft && *action == glfw::Action::Press
    {
        return MouseState::LeftUp;
    }
    return MouseState::NoAction;
}
```

Comment: I found https://hoverbear.org/blog/rust-state-machine-pattern/ very useful when I was considering how to implement my state machine use case. +1 for @isaactfa's suggestion to match on tuples. It works really well in practise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For really clean state machines, you can match on tuples:

```
let next_state = match (current_state, button, action) => {
    (MouseState::NoAction, glfw::MouseButtonLeft, glfw::Action::Press) => MouseState::LeftDown,
    (MouseState::NoAction, glfw::MouseButtonRight, glfw::Action::Press) => MouseState::RightDown,
    (MouseState::NoAction, _, _) => MouseState::RightDown,
    (MouseState::LeftDown, glfw::MouseButtonLeft, glfw::Action::Release) => MouseState::LeftUp,
    (MouseState::LeftDown, _, _) => MouseState::LeftDrag,
    (MouseState::LeftDrag, glfw::MouseButtonLeft, glfw::Action::Release) => MouseState::LeftUp,
    (MouseState::LeftDrag, _, _) => MouseState::LeftDrag,
    (MouseState::LeftUp, glfw::MouseButtonLeft, glfw::Action::Press) => MouseState::LeftUp,
    (MouseState::LeftUp, _, _) => MouseState::NoAction,
    _ => MouseState::NoAction,
}
```

Depending on your preference, you can consolidate the branches with the same result using the `|` pattern.

Comment: Oh this is really concise I like it.

Answer (score 2):

I personally love using functional style with `Option` type, it leads to very concise code, although unlike `if` statements it may check branches that are known to be false.

To use it, you convert boolean typed conditions into `Option`, and combine them via `and`, `or`, `map` and a plethora of other functions available in `Option` type

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9faa91021a8af0ba2e4c46ba584e9ab1)

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum MouseState {
    NoAction, LeftDown, LeftDrag, LeftUp, RightDown
}

fn main() {
    let mut state = MouseState::NoAction;

    let left = (*button == glfw::MouseButtonLeft).then_some(());
    let right = (*button == glfw::MouseButtonRight).then_some(());
    let press = (*action == glfw::Action::Release).then_some(());
    let release = (*action == glfw::Action::Press).then_some(());
    
    // just to test
    //let left = Some(());
    //let right: Option<()> = None;
    //let press = Some(());
    //let release: Option<()> = None;
    
    state = match state {
        MouseState::NoAction =>
        {
            press
                .and(left.map(|_| MouseState::LeftDown))
                .or(right.map(|_| MouseState::RightDown))
                .unwrap_or(MouseState::NoAction)
        }
        MouseState::LeftDown | MouseState::LeftDrag =>
        {
            release
                .and(left)
                .map(|_| MouseState::LeftUp)
                .unwrap_or(MouseState::LeftDrag)
        }
        MouseState::LeftUp =>
        {
            press
                .and(left)
                .map(|_| MouseState::LeftUp)
                .unwrap_or(MouseState::NoAction)
        }
        x => x, // other states are left unchanged
    };
    println!("{:?}", state);
}
```